# How to debug scipy.optimize.root()

Tags: python, debugging, optimization, scipy

I try to solve the following environment:

- given Prices `p = (p1, p2)`, a vector of state variables `z`, solve optimal ("individual") decision `F(p, z)` (on a discrete grid), which is a vector containing `F1, F2`.
- Given a constant `f = (f1, f2)`, find the root ("excess demand") `F(p, z) = f`.

So, the way I attack this problem is [(`Param`, `Grid`) just contain parameters etc.]:

```
def iterateIndividual (Prices, Param, Grid):
    returns F1, F2

def computeRoots (Prices, states, Param, Grid):
    F1, F2 = iterateIndividual(Prices, Param, Grid)
    excessDemand = np.concatenate( ( (F1 - Grid.A)[..., np.newaxis], (F2 - Grid.M)[..., np.newaxis]), axis=-1)
    return excessDemand

def solveEverything(states, Grid, Param):
    from scipy.optimize import root

    guessA = ones(states.shape)
    guessM = ones(states.shape)
    #zipPrices returns object of shape `(A, B, 2)`, stacking the guesses on the third dimension
    guess = zipPrices(guessA, guessM)
    sol = root(computeExcessDemand, guess, method='krylov', options={'disp':True}, args=[states, Param, Grid])
```

There should be a unique pair `p` for every state that solves `f = F`, moreover, it should satisfy the conditions for global convergence. One problem may be that `iterateIndividual` yields a discrete grid, which I do not interpolate on. However, `root()` tells me

```
ValueError: Jacobian inversion yielded zero vector. This indicates a bug in the Jacobian approximation.
```

Which is unfortunate, because I actually wanted to use a semi Newtonian method (which approximates automatically the Jacobian.

Using `broyden1` or `broyden2` shows that the solver is stuck right from the start:

```
In[388]: sol = root(computeExcessDemand, guess, method="broyden2", options={'disp':True}, args=[states, Param, Grid])
0:  |F(x)| = 131.909; step 1; tol 0.9
1:  |F(x)| = 159.687; step 1; tol 0.9999
2:  |F(x)| = 159.687; step 1; tol 0.9
3:  |F(x)| = 159.687; step 1; tol 0.9
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Also: Am I correct to poste this on stackoverflow, or would an other site of the network fit better?

Comment: "One problem may be that `iterateIndividual` yields a discrete grid..."  That is exactly the problem.  `root` expects the objective function to be continuous.